# 3 Field MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a table with 3 fields

```
Device1, Device 2 and Device3
```

My end goal is to display information from each one if there is a device located in them

What id like

> If Device 1 is empty > Show 'You currently have no devices. Click
>   here to add one'    If Device 1 is full > Check Device 2
>
> If Device 2 is empty > Output Device 1
>
> If Device 2 is full > Check Device 3
>
> If Device 3 is empty > Output Device 1 + 2
>
> If Device 3 is full > Output Device 1 + 2 + 3

Basically the way the database will work eventually when I get around to making a script to add devices - The previous device must be full to add another one, so they will always go in sequence.

I'm not too sure where to start on this, I couldn't think of another way to describe the logic for the checking so apologies if it is confusing

Comment: Actually, it makes sense and is basically psuedocode for what you want to do. Have you tried? Or are you just asking someone to write code for you?

Comment: You shouldn't use fields for multiple devices, especially if you want them to be editable. Use entries in a separate table. A bit more details would be useful, not quite sure what you intend to do with this functionality.

Comment: This is a Q and A site. There is no question in this. It just looks like you are trying to get us to write your code for you.

Comment: What do you mean by `Check Device 2`?

Comment: Check device 2 means basically check the second field to see if there is any information within it.

@Piontek Media - I have written code and it failed - I didn't see the point in filling up the page with non useful and non working code.

I'm not even looking for a code answer - As i stated "I'm not too sure where to start" 

A simple answer such as - Take a look at this function > or < this type of query would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Device1 = '' OR Device1 IS NULL
            THEN 'You currently have no devices. Click here to add one'
            WHEN Device2 = '' OR Device2 IS NULL
            THEN Device1
            WHEN Device3 = '' OR Device3 IS NULL
            THEN CONCAT(Device1,' + ',Device2)
            ELSE CONCAT(Device1,' + ',Device2,' + ',Device3)
       END AS output
     , Device1
     , Device2
     , Device3
  FROM mytable
```